# Routes: Add multiple components with the needed data

Tags: angular

I have 3 components. If I run them on AppComponent, they all work:

```html
<app-sections #appSection></app-sections>
<app-form #mainForm [section]="appSection.currentSection"></app-form>
<app-match [bestMatchHTMLElement]="mainForm.clonedBestMatch"></app-match>
```

Instead of AppComponent, I would like to create the URL *localhost:4300/search* for all these 3 components. This is what I have so far:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {SectionsComponent} from './search/sections/sections.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'search', component: SectionsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My problem is that it will get only 1 component but the other 2 components should be added as well. My other problem are the attributes, which you may see in my HTML. How do I pass them?

Comment: You cut and paste the three lines of code of your first snippet to the template of a SearchComponent, and you use that SearchComponent as the component of the route 'search'.

Comment: you can add two more routes for two others component. Right? or you want something else?

Comment: if you want to load all your 3 component in a single route (/search) then you can wrap those 3 component in your SectionsComponent . that might solve your problem

Comment: @JBNizet that means I have to create another component for that?

Comment: @Kazi no, I need only one router for all three components.

Comment: you can create one component and put your desired thing on it.

Comment: Yes: the SearchComponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create one component called SectionsComponent. then in your `SectionsComponent.html`

```
<app-sections #appSection></app-sections>
<app-form #mainForm [section]="appSection.currentSection"></app-form>
<app-match [bestMatchHTMLElement]="mainForm.clonedBestMatch"></app-match>
```

After then, put your `<SectionsComponent></SectionsComponent>` into your app component and it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You should have a file called `app.component.html`. There you paste the code for the sections component. `<app-sections></app-sections>`

Inside `sections.component.html` you should paste the remaining code.

```
<app-form #mainForm [section]="appSection.currentSection"></app-form>
<app-match [bestMatchHTMLElement]="mainForm.clonedBestMatch"></app-match>
```